# No results because of relationships, unless "Bypass content access control" is selected

Tags: views, users

I have a view that lists faculty members in a table. Everything was working fine until I decided to go into *incognito mode* to view the table. It wasn't rendering anything at all. So I went back and tried a few things:

1. Since it was a view/display issue, I thought it was caused from the permissions. So I changed all the permissions to *access: none* (and a bunch of other combinations). This didn't seem to be the issue.
2. Selecting *Bypass content access control* worked fine, but I don't want to use this because of the security implications.
3. Getting rid of the relationships works, but I need the relationships.

Note that this view works if I am logged in as administrator user; it doesn't work when I am in incognito mode (logged out/anonymous user). So I suspect it is a permission issue (given that "Bypass content access control" worked), but I am not really sure.

I have 6 different pages in this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/1276450

The above link solved it for me (#5: Disable SQL Rewriting).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Drupal 9, it was a matter of editing the view for the search, specifically the query options.

1. In the edit interface for your view, click the Advanced link to open up the advanced options.
2. Under "Other", click the settings link next to "Query settings".
3. Check "Skip item access checks".
4. Check "Bypass access checks".
5. Click "Apply".
6. Save your view.

This assumes that you have already configured access checks for your content and tested the search to make sure that sensitive information is not included in the results.